# Blazor web assembly Visual Studio "Script Documents" contains lots of references to BouncyCastle, causing VS to freeze

Tags: visual-studio, bouncycastle, visual-studio-debugging, blazor-webassembly

When debugging a Blazor Web Assembly app, Visual studio will regularly hang when filling up the "Script Documents" in solution explorer. The vast majority of these are for BouncyCastle, which is only referenced by a dependency of a dependency of a dependency (Client --> Helpers --> Serilog.Sinks.Email --> MailKit --> MimeKit --> BouncyCastle)
[image: BouncyCastle]

[image]

Bouncy Castle is the only thing that does this, the rest of the "script documents" folder is just from our solution.

If I remove the `Serilog.Sinks.Email` reference, BounceCastle doesn't flood the "script documents" and I don't get long pauses in visual studio.

I've checked "Just my code" is checked in the VS debugger options.

Any ideas how to stop it doing this?

Comment: All debugging settings for Visual Studio are listed here: Tools > Options… > Debugging > General. I checked all the options, it seems no option could meet your requirements. What I think is that, if you use this NuGet package(`Serilog.Sinks.Email`), then the `BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll`(`Portable.BouncyCastle`) is needed (necessary) to be used/loaded… which may cause VS to freeze. So perhaps you should also contact [owners of this NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Email/2.4.1-dev-00128) for more insights/solutions.

Comment: Thanks, @TianyuSun-MSFT, it's odd how out of all the dependencies (and their dependencies) this is the only one that ends up in the script documents when debugging though. I did wonder if a debug build had been added, given the "src" in the path, which I'm guessing wouldn't exist if it was a release build, but I don't know!